# WUApiLib IUpdateInstaller2 yields Error; Some OS updates install others throw HResult -2145124318

Tags: c#, .net, windows-update, wuapi

**Updates are being downloaded from a local server and not from WUS or Microsoft Repositories. Local server is Linux based which host's the contents for each update.**

I'm not using `UpdateDownloader` to download from Microsoft Servers, i manually download the update content and then use `CopyToCache`.

**These installed fine**

Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows XP, Server 2003, Vista, Server 2008 x86 (KB2736416)

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (KB2542054)

**These Didn't**

> Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 on XP, Server 2003,
>   Vista, Windows 7, Server 2008 x86 (KB2840628)

Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows XP, Server 2003, Vista and Server 2008 x86 (KB2836940)

**How my process works**

I receive this for an install from a local server which i use to download all download content for the update. (The blockquote text above KB2840628 is the example provided below)

```
{
  "app_uris": [
    {
      "file_name": "msipatchregfix-x86_94a84b80b8b45a1ac53a0e5d085513da0f099655.exe",
      "file_uri": "https://192.168.5.108/packages/d13c13c81f94fbb48f39c817a71ff239a31773d3a0e821a968dc42a913892841/msipatchregfix-x86_94a84b80b8b45a1ac53a0e5d085513da0f099655.exe",
      "file_size": 130600
    },
    {
      "file_name": "ndp40-kb2840628-v2-x86_891d50ff3c1322db3fb0fde222ebb0aaa5260272.exe",
      "file_uri": "https://192.168.5.108/packages/d13c13c81f94fbb48f39c817a71ff239a31773d3a0e821a968dc42a913892841/ndp40-kb2840628-v2-x86_891d50ff3c1322db3fb0fde222ebb0aaa5260272.exe",
      "file_size": 13294216
    }
  ],
  "app_id": "d13c13c81f94fbb48f39c817a71ff239a31773d3a0e821a968dc42a913892841",
  "app_name": "Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 on XP, Server 2003, Vista, Windows 7, Server 2008 x86 (KB2840628)"
}
```

With that said, the problem is that some updates install perfectly fine, but certain updates (I believe the ones that have more than one `bundle-updates`) don't go thru, its driving me mad!

I first download each `Uri` and then load them into the update with `CopyToCache`.

```
  var collection = new UpdateCollection();
  IList<string> updateFiles = Directory.GetFiles(updateFolder);
  var fileCollection = new StringCollection();

  try
  {
       foreach (var file in updateFiles)
               fileCollection.Add(file);

       //Error happens here on certain updates. Not all.
       ((IUpdate2)update.BundledUpdates[0]).CopyToCache(fileCollection);
       collection.Add(update);
       return collection;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
     return null;
  }
```

After this, the returned collection is passed through my `WindowsUpdateInstaller` Method shown below:

```
IUpdateSession Session = new UpdateSession();
var updatesToInstall = //THIS GETS THE RETURN FROM THE ABOVE CODE...
var installer        = (IUpdateInstaller2)Session.CreateUpdateInstaller();

installer.ForceQuiet         = true;
installer.AllowSourcePrompts = false;
installer.Updates            = updatesToInstall;

foreach (IUpdate updateNode in installer.Updates)
{
   updateNode.AcceptEula();
}

//FAILS HERE WITH "-2145124318, Result code: orcFailed",
var installationRes = installer.Install(); 
var installResult   = installationRes.GetUpdateResult(0);
```

The update installs just fine if i manually double click on the executable it and install it manually without using the code.

Comment: Is your code running in an interactive environment? And usually these sorts of things leave fairly detailed logs, more than just a `-2145124318` return code. Also, a quick Google yielded [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/windows-update-will-not-work-getting-error/500d9cbb-d394-4f3b-ac32-88ad46414d2a) which might suggest the updates can't connect to the internet? Either because of BITS, proxy settings or otherwise.

Comment: @ta.speot.is http://paste.ofcode.org/tzXzURmFHvLRNpYFpiekFG  I tested running it in debug mode in VS2010. I've tested it on XP, Windows 7. Files are being pushed to the `IUpdate` via `CopyToCache`, i can't have `WUapi` fetch it from Microsoft servers. Also, i have AU Disabled.

Comment: Well the failing update seems to be something related to Windows Defender. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918355, which refers to 0x80240022. It says to try using Method 2 to install the update which is basically "it's all too hard, install it manually". There's a reference to the error [over here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WindowsDefenderErrors0x8024402c0x80240022And1609.aspx) but not unlikely that the instructions are out of date...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the `WUApi` exposes `IUpdate` which holds multiple levels of `bundleUpdates`. Before, I was simply retrieving the top level of `bundleUpdates` which by doing so, made certain updates fail due to missing content required by the update; most windows updates have more than 1 level of bundles.

**For example, imagine this tree like structure for 1 Update (aka IUpdate):**

```
Update 1
    ---> Bundle 1
       *URL 1
       *URL 2
         ----> Bundle 1A
               *URL 1
               *URL 2
               *URL 3

    ---> Bundle 2
       *URL 1
         ----> Bundle 2A
               *URL 1
               *URL 2
         ----> Bundle 2B
               *URL 1

   ----> Bundle 3
         *URL 1
          ----> Bundle 3A
                *URL 1
                *URL 2
```

My Solution was to create a Recursive function to parse each update individually and keep all URIs in a dictionary of key type "`bundleName`" and `list of value`s that will hold all URIs for that particular bundle.

**Like So:**

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

**The Recursive function is the following:**

```
 private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetAllUpdates(IUpdate iUpdate)
        {
            var bundleDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

            foreach (IUpdate bundle in iUpdate.BundledUpdates)
            {
                foreach (IUpdateDownloadContent udc in bundle.DownloadContents)
                {
                    var downloadContents = new List<string>();
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(udc.DownloadUrl))
                        continue;

                    var url = udc.DownloadUrl;
                    downloadContents.Add(url);

                    if (!bundleDict.ContainsKey(bundle.Title))   
                        bundleDict.Add(bundle.Title, downloadContents);
                }

                if (bundle.BundledUpdates.Count > 0)
                {
                    var valuesReturned = GetAllUpdates(bundle);
                    foreach (var data in valuesReturned)
                    {
                      if(!bundleDict.ContainsKey(data.Key))     
                         bundleDict.Add(data.Key, data.Value);
                    }

                }
            }

            return bundleDict;
        }
```

Comment: what were you doing with the list of bundled titles and uris?  Were you calling something to download each one?

Comment: @inquisitor yeah, it gets populated and sent out to a local server that will download those packages and keep them for me. Once needed, i will retrieve the update and install it by providing all the bundle updates accordingly.

Comment: Hello, did you manage to get download links for windows 10 feature updates as well ? It seems line wuapi doesn't provide download urls for feature updates. Could you please confirm if you have same situation ?

Comment: @Cozdemir Its been a very long time since i touched any windows update code, sorry! I will see if i can get my hands on that codebase again later today and get back to you.

Comment: It would be very nice. Thank you so much. I did some research and confirmed that wsus server  has all this links for windows updates but when you query updates via wuapi there are no links for feature updates.